# SMO Equivalent to SET HADR OFF

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, smo, alwayson

In SMO (C#), what is the equivalent to...

```
ALTER DATABASE db SET HADR OFF;
```

I've looked in the documentation for both the Database and AvailabilityDatabase classes and nothing is really jumping out at me.

The end goal here is to drop a database that is a member of an Availability Group. Currently, we are doing this by first turning HADR off and then dropping the database on all secondary servers, and then, on the primary server, removing the database from the Availability Group and dropping the database there.

Comment: Good question. I think you cannot perform that programmatically using C# (only by using SQL Server Management Studio or Powershell). Even this link gives no information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213326.aspx

Comment: My *suspicion* at the moment is that the AvailabilityDatabase.LeaveAvailabilityGroup method, when performed on the secondary server, is the equivalent action. My suspicion remains untested, though. I will keep this question up-to-date with my findings. Thanks for your input!

Comment: I think that your suspicion may be right. I'll look into it as well tomorrow.

Comment: I am not too sure but I think your suspicion is the right one. Unfortunately I can't test it yet. I am curious to your findings to

Comment: Unfortunately my suspicion appears to be *incorrect*. When I call LeaveAvailabilityGroup on the secondary I get ````The database ... failed to leave the availability group ... on the availability replica ...````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the process I've settled on for using SMO to drop a database that is joined to an AlwaysOn Availability Group...

```
Server primaryServer = new Server();
AvailabilityDatabase pDb = primaryServer.AvailabilityGroups[agName].AvailabilityDatabases[dbName];
pDb.SuspendDataMovement();
while (!pDb.IsSuspended)
{
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
  pDb.Refresh();
}

foreach (var secondary in secondaryServers)
{
  AvailabilityDatabase sDb = secondary.AvailabilityGroups[agName].AvailabilityDatabases[dbName];
  sDb.SuspendDataMovement();
  while (!sDb.IsSuspended)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    sDb.Refresh();
  }

  sDb.LeaveAvailabilityGroup(); // this appears to be the equivalent of SET HADR OFF

  Database db = secondary.Databases[dbName];
  db.UserAccess = DatabaseUserAccess.Single;
  secondary.KillAllProcesses(dbName);
  db.Drop();
}

pDb.Drop();

Database db = primaryServer.Databases[dbName];
db.UserAccess = DatabaseUserAccess.Single;
primaryServer.KillAllProcesses(dbName);
db.Drop();
```